# What are the Material Design Guidelines for ImageButtons?

Tags: android, material-design, design-guidelines

What do the Material Design Guidelines say about `ImageButtons` (not toggle buttons)?

I cannot find anything about them here: https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html.

- How should they look?
- When should they be used and when?
- How should they behave?

**Example:** I have navigation buttons left/right to switch through days and I wonder if they are conform with Material Design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this from source of **Decompiled ImageButton** class.

> Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular {@link android.widget.Button}, with the standard button
>   background  that changes color during different button states. The image on the surface  of the button is defined either by the {@code android:src} attribute in the {@code } XML element or by the  {@link #setImageResource(int)} method.
>   To remove the standard button background image, define your own  background image or set the background color to be transparent.
>   To indicate the different button states (focused, selected, etc.),  you can  define a different image for each state. E.g., a blue image by default, an orange one for when focused, and a yellow one for when pressed. An easy way to do this is with an XML drawable "selector."